# object literal - a different key must be given explicitly

Tags: javascript

Helllo, I am slowly working through the ES6 code at http://es6katas.org/.

I'm stuck on the this piece of code:

```
const func = () => func;

it('a different key must be given explicitly, just like before ES6', () => {
  const short = {func};
  assert.deepEqual(short, {otherKey: func});
});
```

How can I get my test to pass by using an explicit key? I'm not allowed to change the assertion, just the other code.

Comment: `const short = {otherKey: func};`

Comment: @melpomene: That doesn't test anything.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder It makes the test pass.

Comment: @melpomene: It makes the test pass, but again, it *doesn't test anything*.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder That's not the point.

Comment: @melpomene: Of course that's the point. Otherwise, he may as well write `assert.deepEqual({foo:"bar"}, {foo:"bar"});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of this exercise is to demonstrate that if you want to use a key that doesn't match the name of the variable holding the value, you need to give the key explicitly, just like you would have before ES6.

It's a pretty trivial exercise, and the variable name `short` makes the resulting code look a bit odd, but it's simply:

```
it('a different key must be given explicitly, just like before ES6', () => {
  const short = {otherKey: func};
  assert.deepEqual(short, {otherKey: func});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If we have to keep the assertion unchanged, then you need to update the code so the "other key" given matches the name of the variable used in `short`.

For instance:

```
const func = () => func;

it('a different key must be given explicitly, just like before ES6', () => {
  const otherKey = func;
  const short = {otherKey};
  assert.deepEqual(short, {otherKey: func});
});
```

Comment: That doesn't use an explicit key.

Comment: @melpomene: Yes, it does: `otherKey` in the first example, `func` in the second.

Comment: No, `{otherKey}` uses an implicit key derived from the variable name. An explicit key looks like `{ keyHere: valueHere }`. Also, the test name says "*a different key*", i.e. one that doesn't match the variable name.

Comment: @melpomene: Look more closely. Here's the explicit key in the first example: `assert.deepEqual(short, {otherKey: func});` Note the `otherKey:` part. That would be explicit. And a key.

Comment: @melpomene: *"the test name says "a different key""* `otherKey` is a different key.

Comment: The `assert` line is part of the test template, as is the test name. The exercise tells you to provide an explicit key to make the test pass; it wouldn't make sense for it to refer to the `assert` (i.e. code you didn't write).

Comment: @melpomene: I'm sorry, but I just don't accept your interpretation of that, the assert is an integral part of the test. But that's fine. Reasonable people can disagree. I can also see what you're saying in your first comment on the question, although I disagree with it, I understand it.

Comment: T.J. Crowder, I see what you're saying, but the issue is that these exercises are designed to teach ES6 syntax, not actually be useful unit tests. They explicitly tell you not to change the `assert` line - the idea is that the `it` line tells you what you're learning, the `assert` line sets the goal, and the student has to edit the rest of the code in the test to make the `assert` work. In this case it's pretty trivial - just showing that if the key doesn't match the variable name, it's specified explicitly as it would have been either way before ES6. @melpomene's solution is what's intended

Comment: @CupawnTae: My first example above **does** leave the `assert` line entirely alone (you were right about the second, I'll remove it). I don't think melpromene's solution (and yours) makes much sense from a learning perspective at all, but again, reasonable people can disagree.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder the minimal learning aspect is just because this particular one is just a very trivial exercise. If you look at the other exercises they follow the same pattern - e.g. one of them you just change `{x}` to `{y}`, but in order to do that you have to actually write a bit of code that uses the shorthand. I assume the idea is that by actually writing the code (however trivial) it will aid memory.

Comment: My issue with your remaining solution is that you're not actually writing the code that the exercise is demonstrating - you're writing another example of the shorthand. If you think of the `assert` as an opaque "check my answer" test, and the exercise as "write code that creates an object using longhand notation, where the key is `otherKey` and the value is `func`" it makes sense